# Look up value from row and column headers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix similar to the one below. I want to make a function where you pass in two letters ("A" and "B") where it then looks up and returns the value found in the row A to column B cell (which would be 2). Currently using numpy.

```
    "A"     "B"     "C"
"A"  0       2       3
"B"  2       0       4
"C"  0       4       0
```

Comment: What is your array dtype?

Comment: int64 - The headers are actually int too but was planning to replace them with letters. Not sure if I can even do that in numpy.

Comment: That's the thing, you can't easily do what you've described in numpy so it's kind of a confusing question.  You might be interested in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) instead

Comment: Yup, use pandas. It suits better for your question.

Comment: I also agree with using pandas instead, but I still gave you a way to do it...

Comment: was it what you were looking for? thanks in advance

Comment: Yup! worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Also guys I'll check out pandas too, thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by creating a little helper to get the array coordinates from  letters:

```
import string
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [2, 0, 4], [0, 4, 0]], np.int64)
mapping = {letter:idx for (idx, letter) in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}

def coords(letter1, letter2):
    """ assuming that the letters are always uppercase """
    return mapping[letter1], mapping[letter2]

# now to get what you wanted:
result  = x[coords('A', 'B')]
# or really short method:
result = x[string.ascii_uppercase.index('A'), string.ascii_uppercase.index('B')]

print result
```

output:

```
2
```

You could also skip building a mapping and just do `string.ascii_uppercase.index(<letter>)` but having a mapping helps if you use the `coords` helper really intensively.